# Display an image from another website in Laravel 4

Tags: php, image, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am looking to display an image from another site in laravel. Here is the code snippet I am using in a view to display the image for a real estate listing.

```
<tr>
    <th>Image</th>
    <td>{{ HTML::image($listing->image) }}</td>
</tr>
```

Where `$listing->image` is the URL to the image. (which is located on a different web site) The problem is that when the final HTML is produced, it places my site's URL at the beginning of the image src attribute.

I am expecting

```
<img src="othersite.com/image_path">
```

But Laravel is placing my site's URL first like so:

```
<img src="mysite.com/othersite.com/image_path">
```

Is there a way to stop Laravel from placing my site's URL first and just placing the URL that I am giving?

I have tried the following:

```
<td><img src="{{$listing->image}}"/><td>
```

and it still continues to place my site's URL in there first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add http:// to your image name. An example:

```
{{ HTML::image('http://' . $listing->image) }}
```

Or, if it's really outside your project, just add the `http://` to your image column in database.